# How to interpret yaml error messa with Rmarkdown?

Tags: r-markdown, knitr, bookdown

Does anybody have a clue on how to find the control character in this error:

```
Error in yaml::yaml.load(..., eval.expr = TRUE) : 
  Reader error: control characters are not allowed: #9D at 2116
Calls: <Anonymous> ... parse_yaml_front_matter -> yaml_load -> <Anonymous>
```

What's *#9D* and *at 2116*?

Comment: Can you post the YAML header from the top of your markdown document?

Comment: I have tried, but stackoverflow tells me 'my post is only code'...

Comment: I am having this issue only in Windows 10, in Ubuntu the report compiles. It's package I am developing, the source is open at https://github.com/lfpdroubi/ufscdown. The path to the file is https://github.com/lfpdroubi/ufscdown/blob/master/inst/rmarkdown/templates/thesis/skeleton/skeleton.Rmd

Comment: I don't see anything problematic off hand, but it's a complex header. Could be one of the dependencies is broken on Windows if there's a cross platform issue. Can you reproduce the problem with a simpler file on both platforms?

Comment: That's why I wanted to know the interpretation of the error message, so I could debug. I guess _2116_ may be the character from the beginning, but I have no clue about _#9D_

Comment: I compiled your RMD file on a Windows 10 PC and did not get this error. Did you really compile the Skeelton.Rmd or index.Rmd without any change? My idea is to copy the lines, delete the file and save everything under a new file with the required name.